# python 2 equivalent to get_dummies with pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am seeking clarity as to why my code cannot access specific column values using dummie values using the following example data:

```
df

            shop   category  subcategory     season
date                
2013-09-04  abc    weddings  shoes           winter
2013-09-04  def    jewelry   watches         summer
2013-09-05  ghi    sports    sneakers        spring
2013-09-05  jkl    jewelry   necklaces       fall
```

Here is my basic code:

```
wedding_df = df[["weddings","winter","summer","spring","fall"]]
```

I'm using Python 2 with my notebook, so it very well may be a version issue and require `get_dummies()`, but some guidance would be helpful. Idea is to create a dummy dataframe that uses binary to say if a row had a wedding category and what season.

Here is an example of what I'm looking to achieve:

```
        weddings    winter  summer  spring  fall
71654   1.0         0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
72168   1.0         0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
72080   1.0         0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
```

with `corr()`:

```
         weddings   fall     spring    summer      winter
weddings NaN        NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
fall     NaN       1.000000  0.054019   -0.331866   -0.012122
spring   NaN       0.054019  1.000000   -0.857205   0.072420
summer   NaN       -0.331866 -0.857205  1.000000    -0.484578
winter   NaN       -0.012122 0.072420   -0.484578   1.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `prefix` and `prefix_sep`  assign them to blank , then you are able to `df[["weddings","winter","summer","spring","fall"]]`

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df,prefix = '', prefix_sep = '' )
df
            abc  def  ghi  jkl  jewelry  sports  weddings  necklaces  shoes  \
date                                                                          
2013-09-04    1    0    0    0        0       0         1          0      1   
2013-09-04    0    1    0    0        1       0         0          0      0   
2013-09-05    0    0    1    0        0       1         0          0      0   
2013-09-05    0    0    0    1        1       0         0          1      0   
            sneakers  watches  fall  spring  summer  winter  
date                                                         
2013-09-04         0        0     0       0       0       1  
2013-09-04         0        1     0       0       1       0  
2013-09-05         1        0     0       1       0       0  
2013-09-05         0        0     1       0       0       0
```

Update

```
pd.get_dummies(df.loc[df['category']=='weddings',['category','season']],prefix = '', prefix_sep = '' )
Out[820]: 
            weddings  winter
date                        
2013-09-04         1       1
```

Comment: I edited my post to show an example of what I'm seeking to achieve

Comment: @Mr.Jibz I can not get it , can you explain how to use your input get your output ?

Comment: the objective is to filter the cateogry column to `weddings` inputs only, as well as whatever `season` value corresponds with the `weddings` entry so that I can have five columns, `weddings`, `winter`, `summer`, `spring`, `fall`, all of which would be indexed by the time index shown above.

Comment: @Mr.Jibz updated ... still can not match your output , ithink maybe you did not provide all sample data here ?

Comment: I re-edited my query to show that when using `corr()` the `weddings` column shows `NaN` value. Is it because of how I'm setting parameters under `get_dummies()`? It shows it's a column like all the `season` columns...

Comment: any thoughts on my last query?

Comment: @Mr.Jibz it is better open a new topic about your new question